# Simple python inheritance

Tags: python, inheritance, constructor

```
class Animal(object):
    def __init__(self, nlegs=4):
        self.nlegs = nlegs
    
class Cat(Animal):
    def __init__(self, talk='meow'):
        self.talk = talk

class Dog(Animal):
    def __init__(self, talk='woof'):
        self.talk = talk
```

1. Why does my cat `tom = Cat()` not have an `nlegs` attribute?
2. Should we explicitly call `Animal.__init__()` from within `Cat.__init__`, or should we use [`super`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super) here?
3. What if we want to create a cat with 5 legs, should we add additional arguments to the `Cat.__init__` interface?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To build on what everyone else has said, yes, you'll need to call the parent's `__init__` method.

It's generally best to use super.  However, in certain cases (particularly when you're inheriting from multiple classes) it can be a big gotcha. I'll avoid going into detail, there are no shortage of [various articles which discuss it](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&q=python%20multiple%20inheritance%20super&aq=f&aqi=p-p1g1&aql=&oq=). (Also, there are some oddities with some of the other "special" functions. For example, you can do `super(SomeCls, self).__getitem__(5)` but `super(SomeCls, self)[5]` won't work.)

As a simplistic example of why it's a good idea to use it, you could make `Dog` and `Cat` inherit from `Mammal` (which inherits from `Animal`) and not have to change places in your code other than which class `Dog` and `Cat` inherit from.

As for why your `tom` instance doesn't have `tom.nlegs`, it's because you haven't called `Animal`'s `__init__` method.

Also remember that not everything needs to be set at initialization time.  For this example, it makes more sense not to set things like `nlegs` in the `__init__` method.  Instead, just set it directly in the class. E.g.

```
class Mammal(object):
    nlimbs = 4
    def __init__(self):
        print "I'm a mammal!"

class Cat(Mammal):
    def __init__(self, color="calico"):
        self.color = color
        super(Cat, self).__init__()
        print "I have {0} legs I am {1}".format(self.nlimbs, self.color)

class FiveLeggedCat(Cat):
    nlimbs = 5
```

Basically, if something is likely to change from instance to instance (e.g. the color of the cat) or needs to be done at initialization (e.g. opening a file), then it probably should be set in `__init__`.

Otherwise, if it's something we want to be the same for any instance of the class, it can be cleaner to set it directly in the class definition.

Also, attributes set this way will be available to documentation tools (e.g. the built-in `help` function), whereas attributes set at initialization won't be.

Comment: @wim - I added some edits to clarify things a bit. In a nutshell, if it's something that's going to change with every instance, then set in in the `__init__` constructor. Otherwise, make the `__init__` function simpler, and set it directly in the class definition.  Hope that helps!

Comment: I don't think every animal has 4 legs (some don't have any). So, it shouldn't be part of Animal class.

Comment: @JBernardo - True, and good point!  I made it into a mammal class instead.  Excepting special cases such as whales (which still have legs, they've just become vestigial internal bones) most (un injured/mutant) mammals have 4 limbs, so it's a better fit.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`super`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#super):

```
class Cat(Animal):
    def __init__(self, talk='meow', num_legs=4):
        print 'Hay cat'
        self.talk = talk
        super(Cat, self).__init__(num_legs)


tom = Cat()  #tom is a normal cat
bob = Cat('Nyan', 3) #bob is a japanese defective cat
```

Comment: Yes. The derived class use the parent `__init__` method if it doesn't define one. You don't need to do anything to `object`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to look at the Python docs about [`super()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#super). For example, you would normally begin (or end) your `Cat.__init__()` method with a call to `super(Cat, self).__init__(<any args>)`.