# How to instantiate a child class from parent class

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I want to create a child class from a parent class. This is to reduce redundancy in code. For instance,

```
class Parent():
   def __init__(self, a, b, c, d, e, f, g):
       self.a = a
       self.b = b
       ...
       self.g = g

class Child1(Parent):
   def __init__(self, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k):
          super().__init__(a, b, c d, e, f, g)
          self.i = i
          self.j = j
          self.k = k

class Child2(Parent):
   def __init__(self, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, x, y, z):
          super().__init__(a, b, c d, e, f, g)
          self.x = x
          self.y = y
          self.z = z
```

I don't want to pass parameters again and again for all child classes. Is there a way I could make Child1 and Child2 from Parent class?

I have 30+ parameters and many child classes. It seems very redundant to write out all parameters. Plus, they all share the same parameters as parents.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple python inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6381590/simple-python-inheritance)

Comment: You must specify the parent class when defining a child class: `Child1(Parent)`.

Comment: @DyZ ah yes that was a typo

Comment: If you have 30+ parameters, there must be something wrong with your code design. Have you considered passing a dictionary?

Comment: Well it's bunch of hyperparameters I need to tune for deep learning stuff...

Comment: I don’t understand what you mean by “instantiate a child class from a parent”, because you’re not using those words in the usual way. Are you looking for a way to eliminate the boilerplate of writing all those `__init__` methods (and possibly `__repr__` and other methods) that require repeating all those parameter names over and over? If you, what you want is probably either `@dataclass` or `namedtuple` (or, for earlier Python, a third-party library like `attrs`). Can you look those up, and either explain why they’re not what you want, or ask for specific help in using them for your problem?

Comment: You might also be looking for something a little different, but still involving a factory or decorator that creates or assists creation of classes. If so, reading the source to those libs (and maybe a few simpler ones, like `functools.total_ordering`) might show you the different options to get you started, even if they aren’t what you need out of the box.

Comment: @abarnert I'm quite new to OOP so like you said I may not be using the correct words. I am trying to eliminate boildplate code. What I wanted was to instantiate a parent class. Then from that parent class, I can spawn multiple child classes that will inherit what the parent has. Currently I am in the process of adding and removing parameters. And having to go through all classes to add and delete parameters is not the most efficient use of my time. I will look into `@dataclass` and `namedtuple`.

Comment: @MoneyBall "Instantiate" means to create an object that's an instance of a class. So, when the object you're creating is a class, the thing you're instantiating is a metaclass. Which almost certainly isn't relevant here—all of your classes are just normal classes (which means they're instances of `type`, but you rarely have to think about that). What you're trying to do is to create classes using information from the parent class, but not by instantiating the parent class.

Answer (score 4):

What you're looking to do here has nothing to do with instantiation. That word means to create an instance of a class. You can't "instantiate a child class from parent class", because a class object is not (except in very unusual circumstances) an instance of its base class.

What you're trying to do is to eliminate some boilerplate.

Python is very flexible—instances can define attributes wherever they want, classes can have any signature they want for methods like `__init__` and `__repr__`, etc. This is very powerful, but it also means that when you have a very repetitive class hierarchy, you have to repeat yourself a lot. But—because Python is very flexible—you can write tools to generate all that repetitive stuff for you, or you can just use tools that come with the language, like [`@dataclass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html):<sup>1</sup>

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Parent:
    a: int
    b: int
    c: int
    d: int
    e: int
    f: int
    g: int
    h: int

@dataclass
class Child1(Parent):
    i: int
    j: int
    k: int

@dataclass
class Child2(Parent):
    x: int
    y: int
    z: int
```

That's all it takes to define your classes, including automatically generating `__init__` methods that can handle both positional and keyword arguments and forward the right things to base classes, and `__repr__` methods that display things in some useful way, and static type hints that Mypy can check for you, and so on, without any repetition:

```
>>> c1 = Child1(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11)
>>> c1
Child1(a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4, e=5, f=6, g=7, h=8, i=9, j=10, k=11)
>>> c1b = Child1(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, k=11, j=10, h=8, i=9)
>>> c1 == c1b
True
>>> c2 = Child2(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11)
>>> c1 == c2
False
```

If you read the docs, you'll see that there's a lot more flexibility there (and even more in `attrs`), but the defaults give you what you want 80% of the time.

---

<sub>`@dataclass` was added in Python 3.7. There's [a backport for 3.6](https://pypi.org/project/dataclasses/) that you can install with just `pip install dataclasses`, but if you need to work with 3.5 or 2.7, you'll need a third-party library like [`attrs`](https://pypi.org/project/attrs/) instead. Also look at [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) for very simple cases, which works all the way back to 2.6 and 3.1.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear from your example whether inheritance is appropriate here. Does the child satisfy the [*is a*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a) relationship, i.e., is the child really a subclass of the parent? If it does not then you should consider using [composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) rather than inheritance.

I suggest composition because you mention, in a comment, *instantiating* the parent class and using that *instance* in the "child" classes. So you could create an instance of the parent and pass it to `__init__()` of the "child" classes, thereby using composition.

```
class Parent():
   def __init__(self, a, b, c, d, e, f, g):
       self.a = a
       self.b = b
       ...
       self.g = g

class Child1:
    def __init__(self, parent, h, i, j, k):
        self.parent = parent
        self.h = h
        self.i = i
        self.j = j
        self.k = k
```

Within the child classes you would access parent attributes via `self.parent.a` for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass all parameters to the subclass's `__init__` as a list, pass as many as necessary to the superclass, and use the rest in the subclass itself:

```
class Parent():
    def __init__(self,a,b,c):
        print(a,b,c)

class Child1(Parent):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args[:3]) # 3 for the parent
        self.x, self.y = args[3:] # 2 for myself
        print(self.x, self.y)

Child1(1,2,3,4,5)
#1 2 3
#4 5
#<__main__.Child1 object at 0x7f5d70c3c9e8>
```

Comment: i prefer not using *args for project specific reasons. It seems there is no way to instantiate a child from parent in python

Comment: @MoneyBall Is what you’re asking “How do I do the same thing as `*args` without using `*args`? If so, that’s not possible, but similar things are. For example, if you want a function that takes a fixed number of ages, but that fixed number is specified by a variable at function creation time, you can write a function that creates the function.