# How to assign a class with an if statement in Python

Tags: python, user-input

I have two different devices I use in the lab. I would like to use input from command line to change which device I am using. To elaborate, I would like to type in the name of the device and a variable is defined by that name inside a if statement. Currently when I try the below code I get:

> AttributeError: class temp_class has no attribute 'get_int'

What am I doing wrong

```
from classA import*
from classB import*
from temp_class import*

tempC = temp_class()

print tempC

user_input = raw_input()

print user_input

if (user_input == "a") :
    tempC.__del__()
    tempC = class_a(5)
if (user_input == 'b') :
    tempC = class_b(5)
print temp_class

tempC.set_int(5)

print temp_class.get_int()
```

Output of code:

[image: The first a is what I typed]

What is inside temp_class

```
class temp_class:

    def __init__(self):
        self.num = 8
```

What is inside classA

```
class class_a(object):

    def __init__(self, int):
        self.num = self.set_int(int)
    
    def set_int(self, int):
        self.num = int
    
    def get_int(self):
        return self.num
```

what is inside class_b

```
class class_b:

    def __init__(self):
        self.num = 8
```

Comment: `temp_class` does not have that method in it. You are probably looking for class [inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6381590/simple-python-inheritance)

Comment: What do you expect to see when you say `print temp_class` and `temp_class.get_int()`?

Comment: There's no need to call `tempC.__del__()` explicitly; the purpose of `__del__` is to provide a hook that gets called when the last reference to an object is released.

Comment: @munk I I wanted to see the reference, I do this to troubleshoot my code.

Comment: @racksmey I understand that you dot hat to troubleshoot your code, but you'll find that doesn't show what you're probably hoping it does.

Comment: @munk  I realized that a while back, but it still has some useful information.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of trouble with the code you've shared. I'll try to simplify it:

```
# prog.py

from device_a import DeviceA
from device_b import DeviceB

user_input = raw_input()  # use input() if you have python3

if (user_input == "a") :
    # no need to create an initial "temp" instance or to delete it
    tempC = DeviceA(5)
elif (user_input == 'b') :
    tempC = DeviceB() # DeviceB doesn't take any parameters

# tempC can either be a DeviceA or DeviceB, but both need to have the same methods defined

try:
    tempC.set_int(5) # this will fail for DeviceB because it has no set_int method
except: # this should have a more specific exception type
    pass

print tempC.get_int() # note that this is the name of the variable, not the class


# device.py
class Device(object):
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.num = num
    def get_int(self):
        return self.num

# device_a.py
from device import Device

class DeviceA(Device):
    def __init__(self, num):  # int is a builtin function, so it shouldn't be used as a parameter name
        super(DeviceA, self).__init__(num)

    def set_int(self, num):
        self.num = num

# device_b.py
from device import Device

class DeviceB(Device):
    def __init__(self):
        super(DeviceB, self).__init__(8)
    # no set_int, as this one seems to be fixed in your example
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and response.  Last night at home I figure out how to do what I wanted to do.

I have changed everything, so that I could use a dictionary to hold the object I wanted to create.  I then use my_dic.get('key') to pass the object to the variable I was using in my code.

Answer (score -1):

Last night I figure out how to fix my problem.  Below is what I am now using.

```
obj_dic = {}

print obj_dic

print("a for class a for class b")

user_input = raw_input(":> ")

if user_input == 'a':
    obj_dic = {'a':class_a()}
else:
    obj_dic = {'b':class_b()}

tempC = obj_dic.get(user_input)

print tempC.get_int()

print tempC
```

Comment: You don't need to create `obj_dic`. You can assign to tempC inside the `if/else` block

Comment: @munk thank you.  I had tried this before, but received an error a  'obj_dic' is not defined.  I think that error was from not having an else.