# Create object of class1 from class2

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is it possible to instantiate an object of class one from class two? So far, there is no error but when I call 'identifier.name' from outside nothing happens.

```
class One:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.__name = name

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self.__name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, value):
        self.__name = value



class Two:

    def instantiate():
        identifier = One('name1')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple python inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6381590/simple-python-inheritance)

Comment: What do you mean by "call 'identifier.name' from outside"? What do you expect to happen? What's your question, exactly?

Comment: For instance, I would expect print(identifier.name) to print out 'name1', however, nameerror appears as 'NameError: name 'identifier' is not defined'

Comment: What do you mean by "from outside"? Please make a *complete* example that someone else can run and see the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
class One:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.__name = name

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self.__name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, value):
        self.__name = value



class Two:

    def instantiate(self):
        identifier = One('name1')
        return identifier


x = Two()
print(x.instantiate().name)
```

will print - `name1`