# How can I access superclass attributes through the object externally?

Tags: python, inheritance, subclass, superclass

```
class Student:
    name = "abc"

class Highschool(Student):
    name = "xyz"
    def t(self):
        print(super().name)    # I don't know why this also prints None.

a = Highschool()
print(a.name)              # Prints xyz
print(a.t())               # Prints abc.
print(a.super().name)      # Error
```

My question is, how can I get the last line to print abc without using the t() method.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simple python inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6381590/simple-python-inheritance)

Comment: You're getting an extra print of `None` because you're _printing the result_ of `a.t()` instead of just _calling_ it.  That function prints `super().name` but has no `return` statement, therefore it returns `None` by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just do `Student.name`.  If you needed to get it programmatically based on the instance `a` you could do:

```
>>> a.__class__.__bases__[0].name
'abc'
```

since `a.__class__` is `Highschool`, and `Highschool.__bases__` is a sequence containing `Student`.

Note that `name` is a class variable, not an instance variable -- one `name` is shared by all `Student`s.  This probably does not make a lot of sense for a `Student` class, nor does it make sense for a `Highschool` to itself be a type of `Student`.

Comment: This works ! But it is beyond my knowledge of understanding. I thought it might be something simple as using the super method.

Comment: It's not simple because the thing you're doing is weird.  :)  It doesn't make sense for `Student` to be a superclass of `Highschool`, and it usually doesn't make sense to override a class variable but then override the override by accessing the base class's version, and it almost never will make sense to do this from outside the class in question.

Answer (score 0):

You can create base class object

```
    b = Student()
    print(b.name)
```

Comment: We all know that. But the question is how you can reach this name if you have an instance of `Highschool`.