# Creating an object with an instance of its parent class

Tags: python

Say I have a class `A` that holds some basic attributes, ie

```
class A: 
    def __init__(self,name,value,):
        self.name = name
        self.value = value
```

I want to make a sub-class `B` that has all the properties of `A`, but also includes additional methods, like

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self,instance_of_A):
        # ???        
    def add_to_value(self,x):
        return self.value + x
```

Eventually, I want to do something like

```
a = A('my_name',3)
b = B(a)
c = b.add_to_value(2) # c is 5
print(b.name) # should print 'my_name'
```

Is there a way to do this without explicitly taking every attribute of `a` and giving it to `b` when `b` is created?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to invoke the super constructor in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399307/how-to-invoke-the-super-constructor-in-python)

Comment: Please read more about inheritance starting here [Simple python inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6381590/simple-python-inheritance).

Comment: You can do something like `vars(self).update(vars(instance_of_A))` if it is a non-slotted class

Comment: Why do you want to use an existing `A` instance to create the `B`? Why not just write the constructor so that it takes in the same information, and calls `super`? (Or if there is no additional construction work to do, just skip `__init__` and thus use the base constructor?)

Comment: Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga, that's what I was looking for. I'll use that and `[setattr(self, method, getattr(a,method)) for method in methods]` with `methods = [attr for attr in dir(a) if callable(getattr(a, attr)) and attr.startswith('__') is False]` to give `b` the methods of `a` as well.

Comment: @Dan no, dont do that, **use inheritance**

Comment: Also, *don't use list comprehensions for side effects*: `[setattr(self, method, getattr(a,method)) for method in methods]`

Comment: Why are you using inheritance *and* composition? That doesn't make any sense to me, though I'm not an expert on OOP design. If composition isn't required, then the answer is dead-simple: don't define `B.__init__()`.

Answer (score 0):

You're keeping `__init__()` function of `B` empty, that might give error. To keep it empty, write a `pass` statement in it. If you want to keep it, then `__init__()` of `B` must also have the parameters of `A` so that those value can be forwarded to `A` while calling. If at all you want to keep it empty, better not to write it then, directly `__init__()` of `A` will be called when object of `B` is created. While creating an object of `B`, you don't need to write `B(a)`, directly pass the parameters of `A` and you'll get the desired output.

```
b = B('my_name', 3)
c = b.add_to_value(2) # c is 5
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would go about this:

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self, name, value, extra_attribute_only_for_B):
        super().__init__(name, value) # Initializes attributes of base class
        self.extra_var = extra_attribute_only_for_B # Can give B more attributes

    def add_to_value(self,x):
        return self.value + x

b = B('my_name',3)
c = b.add_to_value(2)
print(b.name)
print(c)
```

Output:

```
my_name
5
```

Since `B` is subclassing `A` you can call `A`'s `__init__()` to initialize the inherited attributes, and also give `B` further new attributes that `A` won't have (I have included an example)