# How can I use 2 classes on a tkinter button?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

The `Btn` class is supposed to overlay an image on a button. In this case, it's supposed to highlight the button once hovered over it. I'm trying to also get a tooltip message to pop up `CreateToolTip` when hovering over the button. At the moment, it is only displaying one of the classes at a time. Is there a way I can display both without them clashing?

Here's my code:

```py
from tkinter import Button, Toplevel, Label, PhotoImage

class Btn(Button):

    def __init__(self, root, img1, img2, *args, **kwargs):       
        super().__init__(root, *args, **kwargs)

        self.img = PhotoImage(file=img1).subsample(2, 2)
        self.img2 = PhotoImage(file=img2).subsample(2, 2)

        self['image'] = self.img
        
        self.bind('<Enter>', self.enter)
        self.bind('<Leave>', self.leave)
        
    def enter(self, event):
        self.config(image=self.img2)

    def leave(self, event):
        self.config(image=self.img)


class CreateToolTip(Btn):
    def __init__(self, widget, text='widget info'):
        self.waittime = 600     #miliseconds
        self.wraplength = 180   #pixels
        self.widget = widget
        self.text = text
        self.widget.bind("<Enter>", self.enter)
        self.widget.bind("<Leave>", self.leave)
        self.widget.bind("<ButtonPress>", self.leave)
        self.id = None
        self.tw = None

    def enter(self, event=None):
        self.schedule()

    def leave(self, event=None):
        self.unschedule()
        self.hidetip()

    def schedule(self):
        self.unschedule()
        self.id = self.widget.after(self.waittime, self.showtip)

    def unschedule(self):
        id = self.id
        self.id = None
        if id:
            self.widget.after_cancel(id)

    def showtip(self, event=None):
        x = y = 0
        x, y, cx, cy = self.widget.bbox("insert")
        x += self.widget.winfo_rootx() + 20
        y += self.widget.winfo_rooty() + 40
        # creates a toplevel window
        self.tw = Toplevel(self.widget)
        # Leaves only the label and removes the app window
        self.tw.wm_overrideredirect(True)
        self.tw.wm_geometry("+%d+%d" % (x, y))
        label = Label(self.tw, text=self.text, justify='left',
                       background="#ffffff", relief='solid', borderwidth=1,
                       wraplength = self.wraplength)
        label.pack(ipadx=1)

    def hidetip(self):
        tw = self.tw
        self.tw= None
        if tw:
            tw.destroy()
```

I imported the classes from another Python file. In my main project this is how they are used:

```py
play = 'Button IMG/Play.png'
playHover = 'Button IMG/MouseHoverAni/Play.png'

playBtn = Btn(toolBar, img1=play, img2=playHover, borderwidth=0, command=run)

playBtn.pack(side=LEFT)

CreateToolTip(playBtn, 'Play')
```

Comment: You need to call `super().enter(event)` inside `enter()` of `CreateToolTip`.  Same for `leave()`.

Comment: Thank you, I have done that but got the following error:                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                      line 40, in leave
    super().leave(event)
line 20, in leave
    self.config(image=self.img)
                      ^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'CreateToolTip' object has no attribute 'img'

Comment: You need to call `super().__init__(...)` inside `__init__()` of `CustomToolTip` as well, but you need to change the function definition.  Suggest you to learn more on inheritance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simple python inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6381590/simple-python-inheritance)